# How to calculate progress of project in sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Am using while loop to print html element dynamic from project list,and i want to calculate the percentage of project based on task list and print in the while loop's HTML element.how can i achieve it .

here is my while loop

```
var ListEnumerator = this.myItems6.getEnumerator();
while (ListEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var currentItem = ListEnumerator.get_current();
    var dynValueTitle = currentItem.get_item('Title');
      gettasklist(dynValueTitle);
    var templatestring ='+ '<div class="card-footer">'
        + '<div class="clearfix">'
        + '<div class="float-left"><strong id="totalprogress"></strong></div>'
        + '<div class="float-right"><small class="text-muted">Progress</small>'
        + '</div>'
        + '</div>'

        + '</div>'
        + '</div>'
        + '</div>'
        + '</div>'
    $('#allproject').append(templateString);
```

This is the loop to execute the function gettasklist(dynvalueTitle);;

And Here is the Function gettasklist(dynvalueTitle)

```
function gettasklist(dynValueTitle) {

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext',
    function () {
        var siteUrl = 'https://abb.sharepoint.com/sites/IAPI-SOP';
        var context = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
        var TicketList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("TaskList");
        var countquery = '<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name="Status"/><Value Type="Text">Completed</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name="Projects"/><Value Type="Choice">' + dynValueTitle + '</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query></View>';
        var countall = '<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Projects"/><Value Type="Choice">' + dynValueTitle + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>';
        var query1 = new SP.CamlQuery();
        query1.set_viewXml(countquery);
        var myitem = TicketList.getItems(query1);

        var query2 = new SP.CamlQuery();
        query2.set_viewXml(countall);
        var myitem2 = TicketList.getItems(query2);

        context.load(myitem);
        context.load(myitem2);
        context.executeQueryAsync(
            function () {

                var id = myitem.get_count();
                console.log("completedtask", id);
                var id2 = myitem2.get_count();
                console.log("alltask", id2);
                var tpercentage = Math.round((id / id2) * 100);
                console.log("Percent", tpercentage);


                document.getElementById("totalprogress").innerHTML = tpercentage ;


            },
            function (sender, args) { alert('Error while updating the data : ' + args.get_message()); }
        );
    });
```

}

This the code I have tried .I don't know Where am doing the mistake ..Please Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use REST API with jQuery Ajax to achieve it. The following code for your reference.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {         
    getProjectItems().done(function(data){
        $.each(data.d.results,function(i,item){         
            var templateString ="<div class='card-footer'>"
                + "<div class='clearfix'>"
                + "<div class='float-left'><strong id='totalprogress'>"+getTaskPercentage(item.Title)+"%</strong></div>"
                + "<div class='float-right'><small class='text-muted'>Progress</small></div>"
                + "</div>"
                + "</div>";
            $("#allproject").append(templateString);
        });
    });
});
function getProjectItems(){
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ProjectList')/items";
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        }
    });
}
function getTaskPercentage(projectTitle){
    var taskAll=getTaskItemCountByFilter("$filter=Projects eq '"+projectTitle+"'");
    var taskCompleted=getTaskItemCountByFilter("$filter=Status eq 'Completed' and Projects eq '"+projectTitle+"'");
    return Math.round((taskCompleted / taskAll) * 100);
}
function getTaskItemCountByFilter(filter){
    var count=0;
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TaskList')/items?$select=ID&"+filter,
        type: "GET",
        async:false,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            count=data.d.results.length;
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
    return count;
}
</script>
<div id="allproject"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much For this code...This code is working fine for me

Comment: If my reply helps you, you mark the reply as answer, it will make others who stuck with the similar issue easier to search for valid solutions in this forum. Thanks.